# Show data point only on selected data point?

Tags: android, graph, charts

I am using GraphView library (http://www.android-graphview.org/legend/) to build my chart. I have a listener in my chart and the purporse is to start with zero data points at the begining. I want to when I click on a specific position from the chart to show the data point icon from the position I clicked.

Example of what I have:

[Chart I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6YDN.png)

Example of what I want:

[Chart I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NPaa.png)

This is my code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    lateinit var series:LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val series = LineGraphSeries(
            arrayOf(
                DataPoint(9.0, 9.0),
                DataPoint(10.0, 10.0),
                DataPoint(11.0, 11.0),
                DataPoint(12.0, 12.0),
                DataPoint(13.0, 13.0),
                DataPoint(14.0, 14.0)))
        graph.addSeries(series)


        var staticLabelsFormatter = StaticLabelsFormatter(graph)
        staticLabelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(arrayOf<String>("2018", "2019", "2020","2021","2022","2023"))
        graph.viewport.isScrollable = true
        graph.gridLabelRenderer.gridStyle = GridLabelRenderer.GridStyle.NONE
        graph.gridLabelRenderer.isVerticalLabelsVisible = false
        graph.gridLabelRenderer.labelFormatter = staticLabelsFormatter


        series.color = Color.BLACK
        series.thickness = 6
        series.isDrawBackground = true
        series.isDrawDataPoints = true
        series.isDrawDataPoints = false
        series.backgroundColor = Color.parseColor("#0D000000")


        series.setOnDataPointTapListener { series, dataPoint ->

            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                "Series1: On Data Point clicked: $dataPoint",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }

    }
}
```